# Is this colidity challenge (Zinc 2018) test case wrong?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

I just randomly picked up this challenge...

The question and report can be found here: https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training3NRM6P-HSG/

For test case `N = 100,000, all performances are different.`, it says: `got 166661666700000 expected 665533373`

For `N = 100,000` all different performance should not it be: `C(100000, 3) = int(len(A) * (len(A) - 1) * (len(A) - 2) / 3 / 2)`, how is the `665533373` calculated?

Paste my solution here for reading convenience:

```py
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    if not A or len(A) < 3:
        return 0
        
    if len(set(A)) == len(A):
        return int(len(A) * (len(A) - 1) * (len(A) - 2) / 3 / 2)
        
    check = {}
    def bt(path, nxt):
        if len(path) == 3:
            t = tuple(path)
            if t not in check:
                check[t] = None
            return
        
        if len(path) > 3:
            return
        
        for i in range(nxt, len(A)):
            if i > nxt and A[i] == A[i-1]:
                continue
            path.append(A[i])
            bt(path, i + 1)
            path.pop()
            
    bt([], 0)
    
    return len(check)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closer at the question! It clearly says that, "since the answer can be very large, provide it modulo 10^9 + 7 (1,000,000,007)".

Your answer, `166661666700000 % (10^9 + 7) = 665533373`, which is the expected result.

So all you need to do theoretically is edit the last line of your code like so:

```
return len(check) % (10**9 + 7)
```